# Different events everytime a button is clicked in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, blackjack

Currently, I'm working on a Black Jack game using PyQt5. I'm trying to create a function that "Hit", as in draw more cards, but I don't know how to make it work.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
import random
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class BlackJack(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        # Setup layout management
        grid= QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        # The cards
        heart=[str(i)+'H' for i in range(2,11)]
        heart_sym=['AH','JH','QH','KH']
        heart=heart+heart_sym
        diamond=[str(i)+'D' for i in range(2,11)]
        diamond_sym=['AD','JD','QD','KD']
        diamond=diamond+diamond_sym
        club=[str(i)+'C' for i in range(2,11)]
        club_sym=['AC','JC','QC','KC']
        club=club+club_sym
        spade=[str(i)+'S' for i in range(2,11)]
        spade_sym=['AS','JS','QS','KS']
        spade=spade+spade_sym
        fulldeck=heart+diamond+club+spade

        # Initial Score

        myscorelabel=QLabel('My Score:')
        cpuscorelabel=QLabel('CPU Score:')

        grid.addWidget(myscorelabel,3,0)
        grid.addWidget(cpuscorelabel,2,0)

        # Card Value
        cardvalue={'AH':1,'AD':1,'AC':1,'AS':1,'2H':2,'2D':2,'2C':2,'2S':2,
                    '3H':3,'3D':3,'3C':3,'3S':3,'4H':4,'4D':4,'4C':4,'4S':4,
                    '5H':5,'5D':5,'5C':5,'5S':5,'6H':6,'6D':6,'6C':6,'6S':6,
                    '7H':7,'7D':7,'7C':7,'7S':7,'8H':7,'8D':8,'8C':8,'8S':8,
                    '9H':9,'9D':9,'9C':9,'9S':9,'10H':10,'10D':10,'10C':10,'10S':10,
                    'JH':11,'JD':11,'JC':11,'JS':11,'QH':12,'QD':12,'QC':12,'QS':12,'KH':13,'KD':13,'KC':13,'KS':13
                    }

        # Initial 2 Cards
        def first():
            global cpuscore
            global myscore
            global cpuc1
            global cpuc2
            global myc1
            global myc2
            cpuc1=random.choice(fulldeck)
            fulldeck.remove(cpuc1)
            cpuc2=random.choice(fulldeck)
            fulldeck.remove(cpuc2)
            cpuscore=cardvalue[cpuc1]+cardvalue[cpuc2]

            myc1=random.choice(fulldeck)
            fulldeck.remove(myc1)
            myc2=random.choice(fulldeck)
            fulldeck.remove(myc2)
            myscore=cardvalue[myc1]+cardvalue[myc2]
            print('Hello')
        while True:
            first()
            if cpuscore>21:
                continue
            elif myscore>21:
                continue
            else:

                myscorelabel.setText('My score: {0}'.format(myscore))
                cpuscorelabel.setText('CPU score: {0}'.format(cpuscore))
                break  
        # Game screen
        cpu_c1=QLabel(self)
        cpu_c1pix=QPixmap('E:\\myname\\Cards for Python project\\red_back')
        cpu_c1pix=cpu_c1pix.scaled(200,200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        cpu_c1.setPixmap(cpu_c1pix)
        grid.addWidget(cpu_c1,1,0)

        cpu_c2=QLabel(self)
        cpu_c2pix=QPixmap('E:\\myname\\Cards for Python project\\red_back')
        cpu_c2pix=cpu_c2pix.scaled(200,200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        cpu_c2.setPixmap(cpu_c1pix)
        grid.addWidget(cpu_c2,1,1)

        my_c1=QLabel(self)
        my_c1pix=QPixmap('E:\\myname\\Cards for Python project\\{0}'.format(myc1))
        my_c1pix=my_c1pix.scaled(200,200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        my_c1.setPixmap(my_c1pix)
        grid.addWidget(my_c1,4,0)

        my_c2=QLabel(self)
        my_c2pix=QPixmap('E:\\myname\\Cards for Python project\\{0}'.format(myc2))
        my_c2pix=my_c2pix.scaled(200,200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        my_c2.setPixmap(my_c2pix)
        grid.addWidget(my_c2,4,1)

        self.bhit=QPushButton('Hit')
        self.bhit.clicked.connect(self.hit)
        grid.addWidget(self.bhit,5,0)

        self.bstand=QPushButton('Stand')
        self.bstand.clicked.connect(self.stand)
        grid.addWidget(self.bstand,5,1)

        # Window's essentials
        self.setGeometry(500,200,1000,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Black Jack')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('E:\\myname\\blackjackicon'))
        self.show()

    def hit(self):            
        print('You hit')
    def stand(self):
        print('You stand')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    BlackJack = BlackJack()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I want to do is use the "bhit" button to draw more cards and have the card appear on the screen. Any thoughts on how I should perform this task?

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better, maybe an image or diagram will help you understand.

Comment: You know in a card game, you can draw more card from the deck. I want to do that with the button.